# In FileMaker, how can I prevent a field from being changed after data is entered?

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, filemaker

I have a layout, call it `ExperimentsLayout`, based on my database table `Experiment`, which is related to table `Scientist` via foreign key relationship: `Scientist.Id -> Experiment.ScientistId`.

Users of my database (scientists) are still somewhat new to FileMaker, and I expect a relatively steady influx of FileMaker novices in the future, so I want to design in a way that minimizes the likelihood of user errors that could compromise data integrity.

In my layout `ExperimentsLayout`, I have a drop-down list box for `Experiment.ScientistId`. Once the `ScientistId` has been entered, I would like to either:

1. totally prevent it from being changed, or
2. throw a confirmation popup, to make sure this change is intended
3. in some other way prevent the `Experiment -> Scientist` relationship from being unintentionally changed

When a user is browsing an `ExperimentsLayout`, I'm finding that sometimes they are changing the `ScientistId` in Browse mode instead of Find Mode, thinking that this is how to pull up the order(s) associated with the other scientist--but what they're actually doing is changing the scientist that the `Experiment` record is related to. As a relatively new user to FileMaker myself, I totally understand why users would make this mistake, since the UX distinction between Browse and Find mode is *very* (shockingly, to me) understated. This is a ticking timebomb for science data integrity problems.

Comment: Note there are a number of techniques you can use to make find mode distinct from edit mode. For example you could add large text on the layout showing "Find Mode" that only displays in find mode. Use "Hide Object When" (this option is visible in the inspector) to hide this text when ```get(windowmode)=0```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to handle it on the layout then the easiest and most flexible way to handle it is to add a script trigger to the field for `"On Obect Enter"`.

- Go to layout mode
- Right click on the field and select `"Set Script Triggers..."`
- Select `"OnObjectEnter"`

You can use the script to exit the field or show a confirmation box etc.
[image: Script Trigger]

Alternatively

- You could add a button to the layout with "Go to field[]" in the script and handle the logic in the button. The field also needs to be placed on the layout. Be sure that the user can't navigate into the field, e.g. by pressing "tab". Remove the ability to edit the field by going to the inspector and turning off "Browse Mode" and/or "Find Mode" in the field entry options.
- There are other options, e.g. put the field in a popover and add a script trigger to the popover. The new window could be a smaller "card" window that will appear over the top of the base window.

Comment: Or you could simply make the field a button.

Comment: @michael.hor257k it is a drop down list however so a simple "Show custom dialogue" with input wouldn't show the list options. The list could be in a new window, say a card window or a popup but that still requires control via script.

Comment: I did not say anything about showing a custom dialog with input. The script could simply choose whether to Go to Field[] or not, based on (a) is the field empty (b) are we in Find mode (c) user confirmed the choice.

Comment: @michael.hor257k if the button method is used with Go to field[] then ensure that the field is not in the 'tab order' for the layout, otherwise the field can simply be entered by tabbing to it. After making layout changes in the future always double check that the field is not added back in to the tab order.

Comment: I am afraid you keep missing my point. My suggestion is to make the field non-enterable. Anyway, the difference between my method and yours is minimal and largely a matter of preference. I prefer mine because all of the logic is in one place (the script).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Nah, "make the field a button" didn't have enough detail to answer the question, it's easy to miss the tab order as a developer and the real users to use the tab order to get to it during normal data entry. It's because the logic isn't in one place, you need to have a button *and* edit the layout to prevent tabbing into the field. i.e. turn off "Browse Mode" and/or "Find Mode" in the field entry options in the inspector to ensure that the user can't tab into the field.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer.